# Why Isn't find_one working in MongoDB C++?

Tags: c++, mongodb

I have a MongoDB 3.0.7 database, created with the mongo shell. The following works fine:

```
% mongo test
> vs = db.myCollection.findOne({"somefield.subfield": "somevalue"})
```

but when I do this in C++:

```
    mongocxx::instance inst{};
    mongocxx::client conn{};
    auto db = conn["test"];
    bsoncxx::stdx::optional< bsoncxx::document::value> docObj;

    try {
        docObj =
                db["myCollection"]
                .find_one(document{} <<
                          "somefield.subfield" << "someValue" <<
                          bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize);
    } catch (mongocxx::exception::operation e) {
        std::cerr << "Retrieval failed (and exception thrown)";
    }

    if (docObj == bsoncxx::stdx::nullopt)
        std::cerr << "Failed to find object";
```

I get "Failed to find object". What am I missing here?

**Update:** *11/23/2015, 10:00*

I've installed the latest cxx driver (0.3.0), and made the following changes:

```
    mongocxx::instance inst{};
    mongocxx::client *connPtr;
    bsoncxx::stdx::string_view connectionString("mongodb://localhost");
    connPtr = new mongocxx::client(mongocxx::uri(connectionString));
    auto db = connPtr->database("test");;
    bsoncxx::stdx::optional< bsoncxx::document::value> docObj;

    try {
        docObj =
                db["myCollection"]
                .find_one(document{} <<
                          "somefield.subfield" << "someValue" <<
                          bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize);
    } catch (mongocxx::exception::operation e) {
        std::cerr << "Retrieval failed (and exception thrown)";
    }

    if (docObj == bsoncxx::stdx::nullopt)
        std::cerr << "Failed to find object";
```

I'm back to exactly the same thing. Calling `db.list_collections(document{})` retrieves no results.

Comment: What version or SHA of the C++11 driver are you using?

Comment: I'd try HEAD on master. A lot has changed since 0.1.0 (which I think is what you meant). We should be issuing an 0.3.0 soon.

Comment: No, it really was 0.0.1. Major 0, minor 0, patch 1. I'll try it again with 0.3.0. Thanks!

Comment: I've posted more details to mongodb-user.

Comment: Just an aside, when examining `optional` variables, you can treat them like a boolean to see if they hold a value (so, just `if (docObj)` instead of `if (docObj == bsoncxx::stdx::nullopt)`)

Comment: I'm sure you meant `if (!docObj)`, yes?

Comment: Yes!  `if(!docObj)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bsoncxx library has two document types, views and values.  A `document::value` contains the actual document data, and a `document::view` is just a reference to some underlying `value`.  `Value`s must outlive the `view`s that use them.

There's a bug in the new c++11 driver with how `document::value`s are passed around.  This code produces a `document::value` :

```
document{} << "someField" << "someValue" << finalize;
```

The `collection.find_one()` method takes a `document::view`, and `document::values` convert implicitly to `document::views`. Unfortunately, this means if you dynamically build a document in your call to find_one(), as above, you can shoot yourself in the foot:

```
collection.find_one(document{} << "someField" << "someValue" << finalize);
```

`finalize` makes a temporary `document::value`, then find_one converts that to a `document::view`. The temporary `value` is dropped on the floor, leaving your `view` `value`-less, like a dangling pointer.

A workaround is to make your value in a separate call, and keep it around:

```
document::value doc = document{} << "someField" << "someValue" << finalize;
collection.find_one(doc.view());
```

I suspect this is what's causing your queries to fail; if not, it's something to make your code resilient to nonetheless!

You can track [this ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CXX-738) for the real fix for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've added that to my code (as well as to the test code) but am still getting the same results. I'll keep looking, but I'm grateful for the hint on making the code more robust.

Comment: Are you sure that the document exists in that collection?  With the fix for document::value I was able to run your code and retrieve the document, provided I had inserted it first.  The fact that you get no results when you run listCollections indicates that there is no item to retrieve.  When you insert a document via the driver, it will create the parent collection if one does not already exist.

Comment: I think so... doesn't the fact that I'm able to retrieve it using the mongo shell mean that it's got to be there?

Comment: Hmm... it's not because you have "someValue" in your driver query, and "somevalue" in your shell query, without the capital?

Comment: No, in the actual code that I'm using to test the query is "apple".

Comment: The program I mentioned was posted on a [MongoDB-users](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mongodb-user/DuplVjyKwlI) thread, if you'd like to compile it and run it yourself.